# Borders in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to apply borders in excel for max row. below is my code and I am getting error 'Int' object is not iterable
Anyone help me applying the borders in excel based on max row?

sheet = is the worksheet

```
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side, 

row = sheet.max_row
thin = Side(border_style="thin", color="000000")
for cell in row:
    cell.border = Border(top=thin, left=thin, right=thin, bottom=thin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sheet.max_row is a number not an iterable object.

You nearly got it working. If want to set border on the last row in a worksheet using openpyxl then try something like this:

```python
row = sheet.max_row
thin = Side(border_style="thin", color="000000")

for col in range(1, sheet.max_column+1):
    cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=col)
    cell.border = Border(top=thin, left=thin, right=thin, bottom=thin)

wb.save('newfile.xlsx')
```